# 301 Moved Permanently - where is the new link to the redirect page?

Tags: redirect

I'm building a program to read a web page. I tried to read

```
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
```

but then I got a response of:

```
    HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently.
```

What I can't understand is that the new link (in the location field) is the same as I gave... so where is the new link for the redirect page?

Here is the response :

```
    HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:26:03 GMT
    Server: Apache
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,X-Forwarded-Proto,Cookie
    Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:26:03 GMT
    Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    X-Cache: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from sq64.wikimedia.org:3128
    Age: 45
    X-Cache: HIT from amssq32.esams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from amssq32.esams.wikimedia.org:3128
    X-Cache: MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org:80
    Connection: close
```

Thanks

---

According to  Eric answer, I test my program again.

I sent the follow command:

```
    GET http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/france HTTP/1.1
```

The response was:

```
    HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 22:36:04 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france
    Content-Length: 243
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    X-Cache: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org:3128
    X-Cache: MISS from amssq45.esams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from amssq45.esams.wikimedia.org:3128
    X-Cache: MISS from knsq26.knams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from knsq26.knams.wikimedia.org:80
    Connection: close

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france">here</a>.</p>
    </body></html>
```

This was expected of course.
Now I sent:

```
    GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france HTTP/1.1
```

And the response was:

```
    HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:26:03 GMT
    Server: Apache
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,X-Forwarded-Proto,Cookie
    Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:26:03 GMT
    Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    X-Cache: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from sq64.wikimedia.org:3128
    Age: 45
    X-Cache: HIT from amssq32.esams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from amssq32.esams.wikimedia.org:3128
    X-Cache: MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org:80
    Connection: close
```

I tried with wget:

```
    wget.exe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france
```

and its ok ! the page is loaded:

```
    wget.exe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france
    --2013-01-18 00:43:06--  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france
    Resolving en.wikipedia.org... 91.198.174.225
    Connecting to en.wikipedia.org|91.198.174.225|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
    Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France [following]
    --2013-01-18 00:43:06--  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
    Reusing existing connection to en.wikipedia.org:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 854896 (835K) [text/html]
    Saving to: `France'

    100%[======================================>] 854,896      573K/s   in 1.5s

    2013-01-18 00:43:08 (573 KB/s) - `France' saved [854896/854896]
```

So what is bad with my program ?

Comment: Could you show the request?

Comment: Is that the actual page you requested? I get a 200 OK response, maybe something in your network is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my program, internally, changed the given address to lower case.
This caused to the link to be with "france" with lower case 'f' instead of upper case 'F' which is needed according to the 301 response.

I thought that URL is not case sensitive, but now I know:

"While domain names are not case-sensitive, the rest of the URL might be" (http://www.wisegeek.com/are-urls-case-sensitive.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The location header is where the new address is supposed to appear. In this case it is identical which would lead a web browser to keep trying to reload it until it gives up with a "too many redirects" error.

If I use the URL you used above, I get a 200 return. If I use `wget --server-response http://wikipedia.org/wiki/France`, the interesting bits are:

```
wget --server-response http://wikipedia.org/wiki/France
--2013-01-16 18:10:59--  http://wikipedia.org/wiki/France
Resolving wikipedia.org... 208.80.152.201, 2620:0:860:ed1a::1
Connecting to wikipedia.org|208.80.152.201|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
  Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 23:10:59 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Location: http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
  Content-Length: 244
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  X-Pad: avoid browser bug
  X-Cache: MISS from sq65.wikimedia.org
  X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq65.wikimedia.org:3128
  X-Cache: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org
  X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq64.wikimedia.org:80
  Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/France [following]
--2013-01-16 18:10:59--  http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
Resolving www.wikipedia.org... 208.80.154.225, 2620:0:861:ed1a::1
Connecting to www.wikipedia.org|208.80.154.225|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
  Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 23:11:00 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
  Content-Length: 243
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  X-Cache: MISS from cp1019.eqiad.wmnet
  X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from cp1019.eqiad.wmnet:3128
  X-Cache: MISS from cp1018.eqiad.wmnet
  X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from cp1018.eqiad.wmnet:80
  Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France [following]
--2013-01-16 18:11:00--  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France
Resolving en.wikipedia.org... 208.80.154.225, 2620:0:861:ed1a::1
Reusing existing connection to www.wikipedia.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

As you can see wget is following redirects from wikipedia.org to www.wikipedia.org and finally to en.wikipedia.org. I'd recheck your URL and make sure you aren't using www.wikipedia.org. If you weren't, it must have been a temporary error on their server.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but still its seems that I do something wrong. I see that I can't write it in the comment. I'm new to this.. will find the way.

Comment: Hopefully I haven't confused you. I added the request for http://wikipedia.org/wiki/France because I knew that would cause redirects and give you an example of normal redirects. Remember that while the host name is case insensitive, the rest of the URI is case sensitive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/france is not the same request as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France. Make sure that your program is using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France. Using the lower case version will cause the 301 forward.